recordreplay_planner_nodes: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [behavior_planner] lio_sam: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [Eigen]
When iam using the docker container of the the autoware iam getting this error please help me to fix this error
when i run this command
rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO
i was getting this error
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
recordreplay_planner_nodes: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [behavior_planner]
lio_sam: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [Eigen]
i was using this docker
https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware/pkgs/container/autoware/280518419?tag=universe-devel-cuda-amd64
i was following this documentation to integrate the autoware to autodrive
https://github.com/Tinker-Twins/AutoDRIVE-Autoware/blob/main/autodrive_autoware/install_docker.md
and iam using ubuntu 22.04 please help me to fix this
